# Cross-platform WebViews

Tags: c++, webview, fltk

I want to contribute to the FLTK project by offering an `Fl_WebView`. For that matter, I am looking for the WebView classes on Mac, Windows and Linux.

For OS X, I know that it is `NSWebView`. But what are the others, how similar are they?

Comment: Windows has a WebView class but whether it does the same thing as the WebView class in OSX is another matter.  The MS one also uses .net fw so it won't be very portable for FLTK.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227702?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to provide means to embed Dillo (http://www.dillo.org) or WebKit...

Comment: Dillo does not do JavaScript, hence its not an option since its more suited as an advanced help page renderer, in my opinion... JS is a mandatory thing nowadays.

Comment: Well, you did not specify your requirements. WebKit is your best option then.